# how long will it take to start coding with symfony?

Tags: symfony1

i wonder how long it will take to master Symfony and use it to code?

i already know mvc + oop and have used CodeIgniter before to code.

are we talking about days, weeks or months giving that i will dedicate 8-12 hours a day to learn it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already know MVC and OOP, it shouldn't be too hard.

I would say that :

- In a couple of days, you should be able to do simple stuff
- In a couple of weeks, you should become a good symfony developper
- And, in a couple of months *(after you finished your first project, maybe)*, you could become an "expert", who really knows how to use symfony's power.

But note that this is probably not specific to symfony : I would say the same for other Frameworks, such as Zend Framework, for example.

Answer (score 7):

About [Twenty Four Hours](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/).

Comment: page was moved..is there a new link?

Answer (score 2):

**Days**, since you already know MVC, OOP and CodeIgniter.

But wasting any more time in SO will not help ;)